# Convert html table to a bunch of divs only

Tags: html, html-table

I need your help.

How can I convert the existing HTML table as it appears below with the  and convert the table to a full functional div table, while using s to create the table only?

Here is my HTML code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
#test {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#test td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td>row1col1</td>
        <td>row1col2</td>
        <td>row1col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row2col1</td>
        <td>row2col2</td>
        <td>row2col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row3col1</td>
        <td>row3col2</td>
        <td>row3col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row4col1</td>
        <td>row4col2</td>
        <td>row4col3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but this question is very unclear. what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code converter you know. It's a Q&A site. People won't do your work for you.

Comment: How do you expect your result html look like?

Comment: Use jquery replace method. This a way to close solution.

Comment: http://programmerscalculator.apphb.com/Home/HtmlToDiv

Comment: Good question. Wanted an answer. Sorry its closed!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a program like Notepad++ and start replacing.

Replace all `<td>` with `<div>` and `</td>` with `</div>`

Then, replace all `<tr>` with `<div class="tr">`, and the final `</tr>` with another `</div>`

When you finish convert all table tags, you could set something like:

```
div {display:table-cell}
div.tr {display:table-row}
```

<strike>And play with different `display`'s</strike>

And then delete the start and end `table` tags manually (that's simple).

Finally you could style a little, adding some `border` and `padding` to the inner `div`'s.

You could get some aditional info [here](http://www.table2css.com/articles/how-convert-manually-your-html-tables-css)

EDIT: As BenM is right, I updated the anwser because needs more info.

Comment: Sorry, that's a really sloppy answer. Something like this is far more complex than just replacing `td` elements with `div` ones!

Comment: With that solution I just convert all the table in five minutes. Is not SO complex. That's what I would do.

Comment: Well done. `div` elements cannot be direct descendants of `tr` elements...

Comment: Yes, after the edit. You didn't tell him what to convert them with though; hence it's not a great answer.